# Submitting form in Vue.js with ajax

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I'm really stuck on how I would work with submitting a form that makes an ajax request using Vue.js and vue-resource then using the response to fill a div.

I do this from project to project with js/jQuery like this:

**view in blade**

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => 'formRoute', 'id' => 'searchForm', 'class' => 'form-inline']) !!}
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="id" class="form-control" placeholder="id" required="required">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

**js/jquery**

```
var $searchForm = $('#searchForm');
var $searchResult = $('#searchResult');

$searchForm.submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault() ;

    $.get(
        $searchForm.attr('action'),
        $searchForm.serialize(),
        function(data) {
            $searchResult.html(data['status']);
        }
    );
});
```

What I've done/tried so far in Vue.js:

**view in blade**

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => 'formRoute', 'id' => 'searchForm', 'class' => 'form-inline']) !!}
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="id" class="form-control" placeholder="id" required="required">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" v-on="click: search">Search</button>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

**vue/js**

```
    Vue.http.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = document.querySelector('#token').getAttribute('value');

    new Vue({
        el: '#someId',

        data: {

        },

        methods: {
            search: function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                var req = this.$http.get(
                    // ???, // url
                    // ???, // data
                    function (data, status, request) {
                        console.log(data);
                    }
                );
            }
        }
    });
```

I'm wondering if it's possible to use components when dealing with the response to output the response data to a div?

Just to summarise everything:

1. How do I submit a form using vue js and vue-resource instead of my usual jQuery way?
2. Using a response from ajax, how can I output data into a div preferably using components?

Answer (score 9):

I used this approach and worked like a charm:

```
event.preventDefault();

let formData = new FormData(event.target);

formData.forEach((key, value) => console.log(value, key));
```

Comment: var data = {};  formData.forEach(function(v,k) {
               data[k]=v;            
            });

Comment: Plus one for the last line to quickly debug values inside the formData object, very useful.

Answer (score 8):

In order to get the value from input you have to use v-model  Directive

**1. Blade View**

```
<div id="app">
<form v-on="submit: search">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" v-model="id" class="form-control" placeholder="id" required="required">
    </div>
    
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Search">
</form>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

// get route url with blade 
var url = "{{route('formRoute')}}";

Vue.http.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = document.querySelector('#token').getAttribute('value');


var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        id: '',
        response: null
    },
    methods: {
        search: function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            
            var payload = {id: this.id};

            // send get request
            this.$http.get(url, payload, function (data, status, request) {

            // set data on vm
            this.response = data;

            }).error(function (data, status, request) {
                // handle error
            });
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

If you want to pass data to component the use 'props' see docs for more info

http://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Passing_Data_with_Props

If you want use laravel and vuejs together, then checkout

https://laracasts.com/series/learning-vuejs

Comment: I think you might want to use @submit="search" or v-on:submit="search" on your form tag. At least for Vue 2.0 https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html

Answer (score 7):

1. Add `v-model="id"` on your text input
2. then add it to your data object

   ```
   new Vue({
       el: '#someId',

       data: {
           id: ''
       },

       methods: {
           search: function(e) {
               e.preventDefault();

               var req = this.$http.get(
                   '/api/search?id=' + this.id,
                   function (data, status, request) {
                       console.log(data);
                   }
               );
           }
       }
   });
   ```
3. It’s better to remove `v-on="click: search"` and add `v-on="submit: search"` on the form tag.
4. You should add `method="GET"` on your form.
5. Make sure you have `#someId` in your html markup.

Comment: with the new updated syntax you can use `@submit="search"`